# Creating WCF services (NOT clients) by code and NOT by configuration

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I have a large number of *WCF* services that are hosted on the *IIS*.

All these services have the same `system.serviceModel` configuration. They all have the same binding configuration, behavior configuration and the only thing that is different is the service's contract which is placed in a different custom configuration file for a different use.

Now, Every change I do in the `system.serviceModel` section needs to get done across all the services and that's annoying.

Since I create my *WCF* clients with custom C# code and update them to fit the services, I was thinking about somehow creating the service's `system.serviceModel` via C# code somehow (and every change will be a dll update or something).

So, I guess it's possible to create the service via code.
I also guess that it can be done with creating a custom `ServiceHostFactory`, but I couldn't really find the place I can choose the service's binding.

What's the best way to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a code example from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731080(v=vs.110).aspx) that seems to fit your question: I'll copy it here for reference.

The binding

```
// Specify a base address for the service
String baseAddress = "http://localhost/CalculatorService";
// Create the binding to be used by the service.
BasicHttpBinding binding1 = new BasicHttpBinding();
```

and the endpoint

```
using(ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService)))
{
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator),binding1, baseAddress);
```

Now, this is an other [example](http://geekswithblogs.net/martinsj/archive/2012/10/14/hosting-and-consuming-wcf-services-without-configuration-files.aspx) with a ServiceFactory

```
public class ServiceHostFactory : 

    System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory
        {

            protected override System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
            {
                var host = base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(ServiceConfig.ServiceMetadataBehavior);
                ServiceConfig.Configure((ServiceDebugBehavior)host.Description.Behaviors[typeof(ServiceDebugBehavior)]);
                return host;
            }
        }
```

with a config done in code:

```
public static class ServiceConfig
{
    public static Binding DefaultBinding
    {
        get
        {
                var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
                Configure(binding);
                return binding;
            } 
        } 

        public static void Configure(HttpBindingBase binding)
        {
            if (binding == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Argument 'binding' cannot be null. Cannot configure binding.");
            }

            binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30, 0); // 30 minute timeout
            binding.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = Int32.MaxValue;
            binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = Int32.MaxValue;
            binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = Int32.MaxValue;
            binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = Int32.MaxValue;
            binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = Int32.MaxValue;
        }

        public static ServiceMetadataBehavior ServiceMetadataBehavior
        {
            get
            {
                return new ServiceMetadataBehavior
                {
                    HttpGetEnabled = true, 
                    MetadataExporter = {PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15}
                };
            }
        }

        public static ServiceDebugBehavior ServiceDebugBehavior
        {
            get
            {
                var smb = new ServiceDebugBehavior();
                Configure(smb);
                return smb;
            }
        }


        public static void Configure(ServiceDebugBehavior behavior)
        {
            if (behavior == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Argument 'behavior' cannot be null. Cannot configure debug behavior.");
            }

            behavior.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
        }
}
```

Comment: I've missed the ServiceHost's ctor overload that accepts the binding. I feel stupid :|. Thank you!